Visualizing Structural Vector Autoregression (SVAR) in Python gives error shape mismatch
I am helping a friend with their thesis in statistics and we need to make a SVAR. I have the following output from VAR which I want to use as an input to SVAR (Not sure if that is the correct input) but any input of any dimension I send into SVAR executes but gives the following error when I try to run .fit() on it:
ValueError: shape mismatch: value array of shape (0,) could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape (0,6,6)
The code I have is displayed below, what is the issue and is there a better way to collect the data from SVAR to then visualize it? Should the input be different?
svarinput = [
    [ 1.000000, -0.587525, -0.554453,  0.306329,  0.218910,  0.013468],
    [-0.587525,  1.000000,  0.528954, -0.130117, -0.105632, -0.016493],
    [-0.554453,  0.528954,  1.000000,  0.041466, -0.103796,  0.097468],
    [ 0.306329, -0.130117,  0.041466,  1.000000,  0.265418,  0.068111],
    [ 0.218910, -0.105632, -0.103796,  0.265418,  1.000000,  0.043339],
    [ 0.013468, -0.016493,  0.097468,  0.068111,  0.043339,  1.000000]
]

# # Define your restriction matrix
A = np.array([
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],  # Housing Index
    [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],  # Policy Rate
    [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],  # Mortgage Rates
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],  # Inflation
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],  # Household Debt
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]   # Covered Bonds
])

# # # Create SVAR model with the VAR fit and your restriction matrix
# # svar_model = SVAR(var_fit, A=restriction_matrix, svar_type='A')
svar_model = SVAR(svarinput, svar_type='A',A=A)
svar_results = svar_model.fit()

I have a research question where the aim in to see how Housing Index is affected by a Central Banks purchases of covered bonds. My data consists of, Housing Index, Policy rate, Mortgage rates, Covered Bonds, Household Debt-to-GDP ratio and Inflation.
I planned to do the analysis in the following order and have finished only step 1-4.

Akaike Information Criterion (selection lag - chose 1)
Augmented Dickey Fuller test (test for stationary - did not have stationary in any variable except covered bonds)
Johansen Cointegration test - Test for cointegration since the variables were not stationary
Vector Error Correction Model - Since there was cointegration
Structural Vector Autoregression Model
Impulse Response Function - I understand this part but haven't come this far
Forecast Error Variance Decomposition


Interesting question, but it's off topic here since it's conceptual in nature; try stats.stackexchange.com instead.

If you found statistical evidencie that your system is cointegrated, a SVAR would be mispecified most likely
